# bash test for yum or apt based linux

Tags: bash, yum, apt-get

Simple question -- what's the canonical way to test in bash whether yum or apt-get are present? I'm writing a script that will run on client machines and install unison, then create a cron job for it ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With bash script (or sh, zsh, ksh) you could use the builtin `command -v yum` and `command -v apt-get`.
(yes, the command is named command)

Zero output means it isn't there, otherwise you get the commands path.

You could then use a test statement to test whether the result was null or not.

```
[ -n "$(command -v yum)" ]
[ -n "$(command -v apt-get)" ]
```

Note: A downside to @ansgar-wiechers's suggested `which` is suppressing stderr for if 'yum' isn't present:

`[ -n "$(which yum 2>/dev/null)" ]`

An upside of which, is it isn't a shell builtin.

Comment: With the `-v` option, you can also just check the exit status: `command -v yum > /dev/null && echo "yum found"`

Comment: Or even better: `PKG_MANAGER=$( command -v yum || command -v apt-get ) || echo "Neither yum nor apt-get found"`

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use `which`:

```
[ -n "$(which apt-get)" ]
[ -n "$(which yum)" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
command -v apt-get &>/dev/null
```